# TypeScript - how to import 'os' module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm learning Typescript. To do this, I'm building a basic utility app with Node for myself. For this app, I need to use [Node's OS Module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os). My question is, how do I import this module?

In my Typescript file, I have the following:

`import { os } from 'os';`

This line generates the error: "Cannot find module 'os'". What am I missing?

Comment: `import * as os from 'os'` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I just tried that and I receive the same error.

Comment: also `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: That did the trick! thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> This line generates the error: "Cannot find module 'os'". What am I missing?

The correct code is

```
import os from 'os';
```

Also make sure you have `npm i @types/node`

## More

Some notes I wrote on NodeJS quickstart : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: This will break for TypeScript if the module is set to '**commonjs**' and the target to **es5**. [Arturo Castro's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12718906/arturo-castro) solution `import * as os from "os"` works fine in this scenario.

Answer (score 20):

Just to update this entry:

```
import * as os from 'os';
```

and later, you can use:

```
const hostname = os.hostname();
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing this over the other answer, `import os from 'os'`?

Comment: Sure, the os module has no "default export". And when to use it as `import os from 'os'` TS gives you error: "Module os has no default export".

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are in the right path location
And then follow the below points
1.npm i types/node
Then

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).